# How can I present one ViewController on top of another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have a class that is a subclass of `UIViewController` named `FullSizeViewController`. I also have another class that is a subclass of `UIViewController` called `TQHViewController` (TQH: Three Quarter Height). How would I

1. be able to display `TQHViewController` over `FullSizeViewController`, with the only one quarter of `FullSizeViewController` visible?
2. animate this action?

I'm basically attempting to make something like a `UIPopover`, but animate it so it slides in from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Go to Apple's docs for `UIViewController`, search for `presentViewController`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I've looked into it, and I understand how it works, but how would I make it so TQHViewController is only 3/4 of the height? Where would I change the view's frame, assuming that's what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) TQHViewController   *template;

template = [[TQHViewController alloc]init];
template.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 1000, 280, 450);
```

And you can also set the frame for the subView and decide the size of the subview. if you want animation from the bottom use UIViewwithanimation.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9f
                      delay:0.1f
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.65f
      initialSpringVelocity:0.1f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                template.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 63, 280, 450);
                [self.view addSubview:overlayWindow];

               }

                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //Completion Block
  }];
```

Use like this so your functionalities will not be lost and make nill after the usage.

If anything wrong feel free to comment it.

Comment: I haven't had time to try this out, but from my understanding, doesn't adding it as a subview make it lose all of its functionalities (i.e. IBActions)?

Comment: So you have actions in TQHViewController class right?

Comment: All theoretical, but yes, I would.

Comment: I have edited my answer and am currently using this method this works well for me and feel free to point out any problem.

Comment: Showed the view, but it lost all functionality.

Comment: After looking into it further, the only reason the view was appearing was because I still had `presentViewController` in it. Where are you presenting the controller?

Comment: Am not loading it as nib its just adding your view in main view. What problem you facing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73133/discussion-between-yohan-and-jkaufman).